# Bayesian statistics for a simple finite population

Tags: bayesian, frequentist

This question has probably been asked before but I couldn't find it so here we go.

Let's assume we have a finite statistical population of $N$ members $x_1... x_N$.

Then for sure $\mu = N^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i$ is a fixed parameter of this population. How does it make any sense to assume $\mu$ has a certain distribution i.e. $\mu$ is actually a random variable?

Comment: The purpose of this question is unclear. It seems to say that you find Bayesian statistics doesn't make any sense? Then perhaps you can try other ways to do inference about $\mu$. What do you actually know about the population and $\mu$ in this exercise? Do you have a random sample of $x_i$s?

Comment: @dipetkov Thanks for your reaction! I know that Bayesian statistics does make sense because it's an entire research field! But I try to improve my own understanding how it could make sense in this particular case by someone explaining a different viewpoint than mine. It's not a an exercise just a hypothetical simple situation, to have a practical example to talk about.

Comment: @dipetkov For example a finite set of people with a certain height, for sure there is a fixed height if you would measure every person in that population.

Comment: It is meaningful to ask yourself questions about the ideas behind Bayesian statistics. However, asking for "explanations of viewpoints different than mine" doesn't make a good on-topic question for Cross Validated. You would learn more by reading a book about Bayesian statistics than asking for opinions here. Read the [guidelines](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @dipetkov I just had a genuine question asked from curiosity and you make me feel I'm not welcome with that on this website :(. I guess learning is only done by reading books on your own without any interaction with other people.

Comment: I acknowledged your question is meaningful but disagreed that it makes a good question for the Cross Validated format. I'm sorry that you feel unwelcome just because I disagree about what's on-topic here.

Comment: @dipetkov My question is how the bayesian framework could make sense in this particular situation. I don't see how this violates any guide-lines or is off-topic (like I asked to explain the meaning of life here) but I guess that's a problem on my part because apparantly I'm just too dumb for this website, I guess I will stop studying and start laying bricks. I will delete the question in a bit.

Comment: Or you can leave your question open and see what the community, rather than just me, thinks about it. That's what I would do.

Comment: Or you could have answered it yourself in a constructive way instead of replying the question is not exactly the type of question that belongs on this website, why can't people just be nice in this world.

Comment: 1. Statistics is (primarily) about estimation or prediction when you don't know the value of something.  If you know the value of that something, you don't need statistics of any sort.  2.  Lots of questions get asked on this site that aren't on-topic or are otherwise unsuitable; I just finished making a suggestion on one before reading this question.  Nobody said the people who ask them are too dumb for the site.  Your reaction seems... somewhat excessive, but not justly attributable to anything @dipetkov actually wrote, IMO.

Comment: @Jbowman Oh sorry that part might be unclear, I don't assume that you know $\mu$ but I meaned that in principle this mean exists and could be calculated, so the mean $\mu$ is a fixed parameter of the population which you try to estimate ($\hat{\mu}$) by taking random samples from the population. But in bayesian statistics you assume $\mu$ somehow has a distribution.

Comment: @dipetkov Okay, I now read this back and I admit I acted out a bit sorry.

Comment: I'm glad your question got two thoughtful answers; I hope you don't feel discouraged in any way to ask more questions, on Cross Validated or elsewhere.

Comment: (+1) For a great question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is no different from any other Bayesian model.

While $\mu$ *is* a fixed quantity, your state of knowledge about $\mu$ is limited (unless you have observed all $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N$) and you represent your limited knowledge about $\mu$ (perhaps indirectly) by a probability model.  For example, you could represent your prior state of knowledge by saying that the $x_i$'s are independent $N(\eta,\tau^2)$ conditional on $\eta$ and $\tau^2$.  Specifying your prior also on $\eta$ and $\tau^2$ this would translate to a prior (or a posterior) also on the finite population mean $\mu=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^N x_i$ if you have observed none of (or only some of) the $x_i$'s.

Comment: If we know $N$, it is possible at a certain point to know that we have observed all $x_i$, and we know the population mean precisely (i.e., we should have posterior variance of zero). I'd be curious how a Bayesian approach could implement this kind of prior information. I suspect assuming $x_i$s drawn independently conditionally on their prior as in standard exchangeability models won't do.

Comment: @ChristianHennig I guess using a multivariate normal prior with negative correlations between the $x_i$'s would do, maybe conditional on some scale parameter $\tau$?  The $x_i$'s would then have an exchangeable distribution but, yes, they would not be conditionally independent.

Answer (score 6):

The apparently complete population you have might only be a sample from a larger, potentially infinite or hypothetical "hyper-population" that's of interest.

For example, one tacit assumption of your setup is that $x_i$ is exact. This is rarely the case. Even if you can measure to the gram, a person's body mass fluctuates by a few pounds over the course of a day. Test scores are even worse.

Similarly, the complete population might not actually exist. If you wanted to know whether American 4th graders were taller than Canadian 4th graders, you would probably sample a few classes from each country and do some inference. If you were mono-manically obsessed, you might try to do a complete census of the kids in each country, but that doesn't really work. There will be new 4th graders next year, and the year after that, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for answering Matt! The point you make about the uncertainty you have in reality is very enlighting. But let's say I'm sampling from a (finite) jar with balls with integers on it (to eliminate measurement error) for sure these numbers are exact and even though I didn't observe the mean, it still exists sort off and hence is determined and can't have a distribution, or am I seeing this wrong?